Topological vector space characterization
I am following the notes by Hormander "Linear Functional Analysis". He defines a topological vector space V over a field K in the usual way, that is vector space operations of addition and multiplication are continuous.
He also makes the following observation
$ (x + x_0, y + y_0) \rightarrow x + y + x_0 + y_0$
and
$ (a+a_0,x+x_0) \rightarrow (a+a_0)(x+x_0) = ax + a_0x_0 + ax_0 + a_0x$.
Then he claims "then the continuity of vector operations reduces to the following conditions on the nbhds of zero"

$(x,y) \rightarrow x + y$ is continuous at $(0,0)$
$(a,x) \rightarrow ax$ is continuous at $(0,0)$
$x \rightarrow a_0x$ is continuous at $0$ for every $a_0$
$a \rightarrow ax_0$ is continuous at $0$ for every $x_0$

I am not sure what the word "reduces" means. Does it mean that continuity of vector operations imply the four items above? Is it if and only if claim?
Edit: thanks to @Malady comment, I realized it is if and only if claim. The "only if" direction is trivial, but I struggle to prove the "if" direction (as I understood it): given a vector space V endowed with a system of nbhds $\{\nu_v\}_{v \in V}$ (or topology $\tau$), if the topology is such that the four maps above are continuous, then $(V,\tau)$ is a TVS.
I came by this answer, which seems to claim we need stronger assumptions on $\tau$ to prove TVS (and I agree, I think if I assume that topology is translation invariant, it becomes almost trivial).
Please help clear the confusion.

That it is if and only if.

@Malady thanks!

Hi @Dave, thanks for the comment. The author uses "the nbhds", and I did not pay enough attention to this formulation.  I also fail to see what difference it makes (I am sorry for bein so ignorant). Given the topology on V (which is given by the fundamental system of nbhds or collection of open sets), we know what product topology on $V \times V$ and $K \times V$ is. So we can evaluate the four claims above.

I'll delete my comments shortly, because in part they're based on a too quick reading of something I've forgotten a bit about. That said, I still think for the "if" half of "if and only if" it would help if the author was more explicit as to whether each of #1-4 implies continuity of the two operations or whether we need #1-4 together (i.e. assume "#1 and #2 and #3 and #4") to deduce continuity of the two operations.

See this post for the non-trivial direction.
